# Pass Data Value from MongoDB to ejs Template in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have an express app where I'm using ejs for rendering the views. For example, this is one of the views I have:

```
<a href="/admin/categories" class="list-group-item">
                            <span style="margin-right: 6px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>
                            Categories
                            <span class="badge categoriesCount"><%= catCount %></span> <!-- get data from mongo -->
                        </a>
```

and in my routes file, I have gotten the values from mongodb and tried passing them into the view like say:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {

let cat_count = 0,
    prod_count = 0,
    user_count = 0,
    order_count = 0;

Category.count({}, (err, count) => {
    if (!err) {
        cat_count = count;
        console.log('Cat count from db:\t' + count);
    } else {
        console.error('Error Fetching Categories Count:\t' + err);
    }
});

Products.count({}, (err, count) => {
    if (!err) {
        prod_count = count;
        console.log('Prod count from db:\t' + count);
    } else {
        console.error('Error Fetching Products Count:\t' + err);
    }
});

Users.count({}, (err, count) => {
    if (!err) {
        user_count = count;
        console.log('User count from db:\t' + count);
    } else {
        console.error('Error Fetching Users Count:\t' + err);
    }
});

Orders.count({}, (err, count) => {
    if (!err) {
        order_count = count;
        console.log('Orders count from db:\t' + count);
    } else {
        console.error('Error Fetching Orders Count:\t' + err);
    }
});

res.render('index', {
    catCount: cat_count,
    prodCount: prod_count,
    userCount: user_count,
    orderCount: order_count
  });
});
```

where the `catCount` is an actual argument for the variable in my template. This does not work and I'm stuck with figuring this way out.

I have also tried using the `DOM querySelector('className').innerHTML` but that also doesn't work.

Which is the best way to send values to my template, I would prefer ejs.
Thanks.

Comment: I think what you are doing should work. Are you getting any error?

Comment: @HarshalGangurde No errors

Comment: In my template, when I hover the variable, it shows unresolved variable or type catCount. Any idea what this means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will not work because the values for your count variables will only get assigned after the callback runs.  When dealing with callbacks, you have to note that the code in the callback function will not execute right away when you run the main function. What you have right now is something like the following:

```
// initialize variables
// execute Category.count({}) and call the function that you passed in when data is ready
// execute Products.count({}) and call the function that you passed in when data is ready
// execute Users.count({}) and call the function that you passed in when data is ready
// execute Orders.count({}) and call the function that you passed in when data is ready
// render
```

All these 5 lines of code will run within a split second and it will *not wait* until those callback functions are called. One way to solve it is to nest all the callbacks in one another:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {

  let cat_count = 0,
      prod_count = 0,
      user_count = 0,
      order_count = 0;

  Category.count({}, (err, count) => {
    if (!err) {
      cat_count = count;
      console.log('Cat count from db:\t' + count);

      Products.count({}, (err, count) => {
        if (!err) {
          prod_count = count;
          console.log('Prod count from db:\t' + count);

          Users.count({}, (err, count) => {
            if (!err) {
              user_count = count;
              console.log('User count from db:\t' + count);

              Orders.count({}, (err, count) => {
                if (!err) {
                  order_count = count;
                  console.log('Orders count from db:\t' + count);

                  res.render('index', {
                    catCount: cat_count,
                    prodCount: prod_count,
                    userCount: user_count,
                    orderCount: order_count
                  });
                } else {
                  console.error('Error Fetching Orders Count:\t' + err);
                }
              });
            } else {
              console.error('Error Fetching Users Count:\t' + err);
            }
          });
        } else {
          console.error('Error Fetching Products Count:\t' + err);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.error('Error Fetching Categories Count:\t' + err);
    }
  });
});
```

However, this is really messy and is known as the *callback hell* in JavaScript. This is where `Promises` comes in handy.

Here's what you can do:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let queries = [
    Category.count({}), 
    Products.count({}), 
    Users.count({}), 
    Orders.count({})
  ];

  Promise.all(queries)
  .then(results => {
    res.render('index', {
      catCount: results[0],
      prodCount: results[1],
      userCount: results[2],
      orderCount: results[3]
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', err)
  });
});
```

For Mongoose, when you don't pass in a function as the second parameter, the value returned by the function call (e.g. `Category.count({})`) will be a Promise. We will put all of these unresolved Promises in an array and call `Promise.all` to resolve them. By using `Promise.all`, you are waiting until all of your count queries get executed before moving on to render your `index` view. In this case, the results of your Mongoose function calls will be stored in the `results` array in the order of your `queries` array.

Comment: You're just awesome bruh and thanks for the explanations, mostly the promise part. Have a great day!!